# Zeroes of $L(s,q)=\prod_{\chi(\text{mod}\ q)}L(s,\chi)$ in a rectengle

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

Denote $$L(s,q)=\prod_{\chi(\text{mod}\ q)}L(s,\chi)$$ Is it true that the number of zeroes of $L(s,q)$ in the rectengle $\{T\leq\Im(s)\leq T+1,\frac{1}{2}<\Re(s)<1\}$ is $\mathcal{O}(\log(qT))$ or even $\mathcal{O}(\log^{\mathcal{O}(1)}(qT))$ ?

Answer (score 0):

If $\chi$ is a primitive character modulo $q$, then we have
$$\begin{align}
N(T,\chi):&=\#\{\rho: L(\rho,\chi)=0, \ 0\leq \Im(\rho)\leq T, \ 0<\Re(\rho)<1\}\\
&=\frac{T}{2\pi} \log \frac{qT}{2\pi e} +O(\log(qT)).\end{align}
$$

From this, we have 
$$
N(T+1,\chi)-N(T,\chi)=O(\log qT).
$$

The number of zeros of $L(s,\chi)$ in your rectangle do not exceed the above. 
Therefore, it is true that your number is $O(q\log qT)$.

Comment: Yes that i knew. Are there any improvement over this ?

Comment: Ah, this is upper bound. The exact number is **zero** if we assume GRH.

Comment: Because of the way you stated the rectangle $1/2<\Re(s)<1$, the number of zeros in that rectangle is zero under GRH.

Comment: GRH was the reason i stated that way.

Comment: If we include the critical line, we already have a nice formula $N(T,\chi)$ for the no. of zeroes.